# adding a custom service worker to create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, service-worker, create-react-app

Per default there is a service worker script in a fresh`create-react-app` project included. I dont need that default `registerServiceWorker.js` and the default `service-worker.js` (hidden and available in build) because I want to add my own Service Worker. I would like to create my own service worker code with es6 syntax also, so just adding a 'sw.js' into the public folder and register it in my index.html is not the best option for me. How can I build some custom sw-code with `ES6` `create-react-app` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you would prefer disable the built in service-worker prior to your initial production deployment, then remove the call to `serviceWorkerRegistration.register()` from `src/index.js` and add your own service worker.

If your site/app has already been in production then swap it out for `serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister().` After the user visits your page that has `serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister()`, the service worker will be uninstalled and it might take up to 24 hours for the cache to be invalidated (depending on how the service worker is served)

The other option would be to eject and configure their built in solution.

Comment: the default `service-worker.js` will still be build and available in the build folder then. I´m interested in writing my own service worker with `ES6` to replace it with the service worker in the build folder. I´m currently just writing my sw code in separate `sw.js` file in my public folder but its just plain vanilla js code.

Comment: There have been suggestions for something like this in the official repository, take a look at: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/pull/2714 - meanwhile, as I said earlier you have the ability to "eject" and do whatever you like :)

Comment: i never had serviceWorkerRegistration.register() on my index.js, but worker keep working , must I remove from /node_modules/react-scripts/template/index.js ??

Comment: i was using and old index, so i've updated i can disabled the worker

Comment: You may be interested in this package as a temporary solution: https://github.com/bbhlondon/cra-append-sw

Comment: I can confirm that  github.com/bbhlondon/cra-append-sw is a great workaround. Saved me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 0):

Ditch all the other ideas and go for the [cra-append-sw](https://github.com/tszarzynski/cra-append-sw). It will save you a lot of time and pain.

It's as simple as installing the package, creating the service worker file in your main folder, and modifying your `start` and `build` commands in package.json file like this:

```
"start": "cra-append-sw --mode dev --env ./.env ./custom-sw.js && react-scripts start",
"build": "cra-append-sw --env ./.env ./custom-sw.js && react-scripts build",
```

And then you make sure to register the separate service worker in dev mode:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  console.log('Trying to register custom sw');
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    .then(function (registration) {
      console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
    });
}
```

If like me you need access to environment variables in the service worker to initialize the firebase messaging module, this is the only simple option that doesn't require ejecting CRA.

---

*I decided to post this answer because I myself overlooked the comments on the other answer and lost time unnecessarily looking for this solution.*